# D3js Appending Duplicate Data to SVG When ".enter()" Selection Should Be Empty

Tags: javascript, d3.js, append

I've written a small application that if a user clicks on the screen a node (circle) will appear. If the user then drags from the a node to another node an edge between them will also appear. Both of these update "nodeData" and "edgeData" data structures internally.

The nodes seem to work fine. If the user clicks on the screen, the new node will be added to the data structure and a function "restart()" will be called to update the visualisation. However the edges don't work as I expected. Instead of updating the current edges and appending any new ones to the visualisation, the "restart()" function appends edges again to the visualisation, so that after "restart()" has been called a few times the graph has way too many edges than it should.

Here's the link to the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/AlexMarshaall/srL3huk9/4/

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">    
  <style>

    svg {
      background-color: #FFF;
      cursor: default;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      -o-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }

    svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) {
      cursor: crosshair;
    }

    path.link {
      fill: none;
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 4px;
      cursor: default;
    }

    svg:not(.active):not(.ctrl) path.link {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    path.link.selected {
      stroke-dasharray: 10, 2;
    }

    path.link.dragline {
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    path.link.hidden {
      stroke-width: 0;
    }

    circle.node {
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    text {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
      pointer-events: none;
    }

    text.id {
      text-anchor: middle;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <script src="/static/d3/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    const svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', 900)
      .attr('height', 500);

    let hoverOverNode = null;   // the node the mouse is currently hovering over
    let mousedownNode = null;   // the node that the mouse went down over

    function resetMouseVars() {
      mousedownNode = null;
    }

    var lastNodeId = 1;
    var node1 = {
      id: "n" + lastNodeId++,
      xVal: 50,
      yVal: 50
    };

    var node2 = {
      id: "n" + lastNodeId++,
      xVal: 100,
      yVal: 100
    }

    const nodesData = [node1,node2];

    const edgeData = [{
      source: node1,
      target: node2
    }];

    let paths = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('path');
    let nodes = svg.append('svg:g').selectAll('g');

    const dragLine = svg.append('svg:path')
      .attr('class', 'link dragline hidden')
      .attr('d', 'M0,0L0,0');


    function restart() {

      nodes = nodes.data(nodesData, (d) => d.id); // Nodes is just the nodes to update

      nodes.selectAll('g')
        .style('fill', "DarkGreen");

      nodes.exit().remove();

      var newNodesToBeAdded = nodes.enter().append('svg:g');

      newNodesToBeAdded.attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${d.xVal},${d.yVal})`)
        .attr('id', (d) => d.id);

      newNodesToBeAdded.append('svg:circle')
        .attr('class', 'node')
        .attr('r', 12)
        .attr('stroke-width', 3)
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .style('fill', "DarkGreen")
        .on('mouseover', function(d) {
          hoverOverNode = d;
          d3.select(this).attr('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
        })
        .on('mouseout', function(d) {
          hoverOverNode = null;
          d3.select(this).attr('transform', '');
        })
        .on('mousedown', (d) => {
          if (d3.event.ctrlKey) return;
          mousedownNode = d;
          dragLine
            .classed('hidden', false)
            .attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.xVal},${mousedownNode.yVal}L${mousedownNode.xVal},${mousedownNode.yVal}`);
          restart();
        })
        .on('mouseup', (d) => {
          dragLine.classed('hidden', true);
        });

      newNodesToBeAdded.append('svg:text')
        .attr('x', 0)
        .attr('y', 4)
        .attr('class', 'id')
        .text((d) => d.id.substring(1));

      nodes = newNodesToBeAdded.merge(nodes);


      paths = paths.data(edgeData);

      paths.append('svg:path')
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", (d) => {
          const sourceX = d.source.xVal;
          const sourceY = d.source.yVal;
          const targetX = d.target.xVal;
          const targetY = d.target.yVal;
          return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
        });

      paths.exit().remove();

      var newPathsToBeAdded = paths.enter().append('svg:path');

      newPathsToBeAdded.attr('class','link')
        .attr("d", (d) => {
          const sourceX = d.source.xVal;
          const sourceY = d.source.yVal;
          const targetX = d.target.xVal;
          const targetY = d.target.yVal;
          return `M${sourceX},${sourceY}L${targetX},${targetY}`;
        });

    }

    function mousedown() {
      if (d3.event.ctrlKey || hoverOverNode != null) {
        return;
      }
      var coords = d3.mouse(this);
      var newNode = {
        id: "n" + lastNodeId++,
        xVal: coords[0],
        yVal: coords[1]
      };
      nodesData.push(newNode);
      restart();
    }

    function mousemove() {
      if (!mousedownNode) return; // if there's no mousedownNode then there's no need to do anything

      // update dragline
      dragLine.attr('d', `M${mousedownNode.xVal},${mousedownNode.yVal}L${d3.mouse(this)[0]},${d3.mouse(this)[1]}`);
      restart();
    }

    function mouseup() {
      // if there is a mousedown node, hide the dragline that's been drawn
      if (mousedownNode){
        dragLine
          .classed('hidden', true);
        if (hoverOverNode != null){
          edgeData.push({source:mousedownNode, target:hoverOverNode});
          resetMouseVars();
          restart();
        }
      }
    }

    // App starts here
    svg.on('mousedown', mousedown)
      .on('mousemove', mousemove)
      .on('mouseup', mouseup);
    restart()

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have these issues, because you're not following correct practices.

```
paths = paths.data(edgeData);
```

the .data method returns an update selection, and it *really* shouldn't be saved in between calls. Instead of reusing paths, you should have created a local variable. You got an odd behavior, because you didn't merge the update selection with the enter selection -- as a result your created paths weren't captured into update selection, and each time that same piece of path data appeared as new to d3. Well, that's at least how I think it went. Adding `paths = newPathsToBeAdded.merge(paths);` should fix it.

---

If you follow the canonical loop, you're less likely to run into odd problems like these in the future. This is how I would do it:

```
var paths = svg.select('g.pathcnt').selectAll('path.edge'); // add classes for selection reference
paths.exit().remove();
paths.enter()
   .append('path')
   .classed('edge', true)
//do not duplicate things; put it after the merge to set for both new and existing nodes
.merge(paths)
    .attr('d', function(d) { ... });
```

I do not recommend preserving selection between invocation; all the examples reselect as needed, thus I'm not sure if reusing the selection is even valid.

Comment: So adding "paths = newPathsToBeAdded.merge(paths)" has solved my problem and I can see how it works now. Because on the next invocation of "restart()" the selection "paths = paths.data(edgeData)" will return an empty selection if no edge has been added. I'm still confused about your preserving selection between invocation though. I found here https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/929623 doing roughly the same thing as what I was doing and he's the person that created D3.

Comment: @AlexMarshall Afaik selections changed quite a bit going from version 3 to 4. Be cautious when looking at older versions (the bl.ocks you linked is v3, while your fiddle is v5). Also I'm not necessarily saying that it's wrong to reuse data-binding related selections (I don't know), it's just that vast majority of code I've seen reselects as needed.